# python/Pyqt5 - how to avoid eval while using ast and getting ValueError: malformed string in attemt to improve code safety

Tags: python, eval, pyqt5, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to prevent to use `eval` based on an example [how-to-avoid-eval-in-python-for-string-conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15159971/how-to-avoid-eval-in-python-for-string-conversion) using `ast`.  The challange is that there are a dozen of these `self.ch%s_label`'s to be made but the variable for it changes based on user input in the GUI.

My code:

```
import ast ...etc.

....

channel_no += 1

ch_width  = eval('self.ch%s_label.frameGeometry().width()' %  (channel_no))
```

When I change it into:

```
ch_width  = ast.literal_eval('self.ch%s_label.frameGeometry().width()' %  (channel_no))
```

I'll get the error:

> File "c:\python\anac2\lib\ast.py", line 80, in literal_eval
>       return _convert(node_or_string)
>     File "c:\python\anac2\lib\ast.py", line 79, in _convert
>       raise ValueError('malformed string')
>   ValueError: malformed string

Changing the code (using closing " ") retains the error:

```
ch_width  = ast.literal_eval("'self.ch%s_label.frameGeometry().width()' %  (channel_no)")
```

What other options are there... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `getattr` to get the attribute from the instance using the dynamically constructed attribute name:

`ch_width  = getattr(self, 'ch%s_label' % channel_no).frameGeometry().width()`
Or step by step:

```
channel_no = 5
attr_name = 'ch%s_label' % channel_no
attr = getattr(self, attr_name)
ch_width = attr.frameGeometry().width()
```

Using `getattr` in this way also means you get an `AttributeError` if an object doesn't have the attribute, as you'd expect.

Comment: @ snakecharmerb.. thanks for the clear example of using `getattr`. I was deeping `functools partial` but this is much more pythonic using default built-in code. Cheers. ... and it works off-course :-)